# Problem with OPE (from Polchinski)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I was reading Polchinski, Vol. 2 pag 12, while I found (10.3.12a):

> $$
> e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(z)}=\frac{1}{2z} + i\partial H(0) + 2zT^H_B(0) + O(z^2).\tag{10.3.12a}
> $$

Now I tried to do the OPE, what I get is

$$
\begin{split}
e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(z)} &= e^{-\log(2z)} + :e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(-z)}:\\
&= \frac{1}{2z} + :e^{i(H(0)+z\partial H(0)}e^{-i(H(0)+z\partial H(0)}: + O(z^2)\\
&= \frac{1}{2z} + :e^{iH(0)}i(1+z\partial H(0))e^{-iH(0)}(-i)(1-z\partial H(0)):\\
&= \frac{1}{2z} + :1+2z\partial H(0): + O(z^2).
\end{split}
$$

Where is the mistake? How can I get Polchinski formula?

Comment: Your first equation is not right. It should be $1/2z$ times the normal ordered exponents. See Vol. 1 page 40.

Comment: Hi MaPo. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Thank you @Haz, for your answer. Now it seems all ok. But I found an apparent paradox:

$$
e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)} = \frac{1}{z}:e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)}: = :\frac{1}{z}e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)}:
$$ 
so that
$$
:e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)}: = ::\frac{1}{z}e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)}:: = \frac{1}{z}:e^{iH(z)}e^{-iH(0)}:
$$
which seems to be a contraddiction...

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576407/2451